# In a Pandas categorical, what is format="table"?

Tags: python, pandas, series, hdf5, pytables

The HDF5 format apparently does not support categoricals with format="fixed".  The following example

```
s = pd.Series(['a','b','a','b'],dtype='category')
s.to_hdf('s.h5','s')
```

Returns the error:

> NotImplementedError: Cannot store a category dtype in a HDF5 dataset that uses format="fixed". Use format="table".

How do I construct the categorical series with format='table'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify `format='table'` or `format='t'` in `pd.Series.to_hdf`:

```
s.to_hdf('s.h5', key='s', format='t')
```

Note that this is also what the error message advises. As per [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_hdf.html):

> **format** : *‘fixed(f)|table(t)’, default is ‘fixed’*
>
> fixed(f) : *Fixed format* Fast writing/reading. Not-appendable, nor
>   searchable
>
> table(t) : *Table format* Write as a PyTables Table structure which may
>   perform worse but allow more flexible operations like searching /
>   selecting subsets of the data

Comment: OMG.  I searched for a solid hour, trying to figure out how to table-format categories... *in the series*.  But you're right, that's what error message says, now that I'm reading it correctly.